# mysql stored procedure to check if username exits

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i am trying to create a stored procedure which check if a username exists in database or not.however, the er

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `USER_EXISTS`
(IN `GIVEN_USERNAME` VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN
    SET @User_exists = 0;
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @found
    FROM `users`
    WHERE `username` = `GIVEN_USERNAME`
    IF @found > 0 THEN
        SET @User_exists = 1
    END IF
    SELECT @User_exists
END
```

Comment: What is the question, please clarify. Also please take time to format your code snippet.

Comment: thank you..i am trying to create a stored procedure in mysql to check if username exits.

Comment: have you any got error in your stored procedure ?

Comment: yes..it is syntax error near the if condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USER_EXISTS(IN GIVEN_USERNAME VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN
    SET @User_exists = 0;
    SELECT 1 INTO @User_exists
    FROM users
    WHERE username = GIVEN_USERNAME;       
    SELECT @User_exists
END
```

Comment: @subhro why you are not accepting and like my answer ? it will help me to appreciate myself to help other